# Haskell- How to keep track of counter in recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm having some difficulty trying to keep track of a counter variable in my function.

I created a function that takes a number as a single parameter and recursively multiplies the number by two, summing all the numbers multiplied by two together, the code below makes it more clear what I intend to do:

```
sum :: Float -> Float
sum x = x + sum (2*x)
```

However, the difficulty I am facing, is that I want the function to recurse only ten times. So I want it to stop once ten numbers have been added together. I tried using a counter to keep track of how many times the function has recursed, but to no avail.

This is what I tried:

```
sumTen :: Float -> Float
sumTen x n
    where
      n=10
       |n == 0 = x
       |otherwise = x + sumTen (2*x) (n-1)
```

I realize the code above does not work, counter `n` would be given the value ten through every recursive call, meaning it will never reach the base case `n == 0`.

What makes this so difficult is that `sumTen` must be called using one parameter. In the code above, I tried to give the function a default parameter `n` with a predetermined value, but it clearly does not work.

Can someone help me make the recursive function stop after 'n' recursive calls?

Comment: Look out! You have 666 reputation, I don't know what might happen to you! In all seriousness now, shouldn't `asin` be `sum`, or the other way around, in your first code block?

Comment: @afsantos sorry that was a typo... 666 lucky me :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a function with one parameter that gives your intended result, `sumTen x`. But you want the recursive call to end after ten iterations. Is that right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an auxiliary function:

```
sumNRec x 0     = 0 
sumNRec x times = x + sumNRec (x*2) (times - 1)

sumTen x = sumNRec x 10
```

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what the OP is asking, but I think he/she would be able to figure out the missing part.

Answer (score 4):

Let's solve the problem in a general way. Start with your original function:

```
sum :: Float -> Float
sum x = x + sum (2*x)
```

As a first step, add an extra `rec` argument. This `rec` stands for "recursive call", and is a function that we are going to call instead of all the recursive calls in the function body. Concretely, just replace any `sum` that appears in the right hand side of the definition with `rec`:

```
sumK :: (Float -> Float) -> Float -> Float
sumK rec x = x + rec (2*x)
```

Now, if we wanted the recursive function executed zero times, we would get `id`. To recurse just once, we can use `sumK id` since

```
sumK id x = x + id (2*x) = x + 2*x
```

To recurse twice: `sumK (sumK id)` since

```
sumK (sumK id) x = x + sumK id (2*x) = x + (2*x) + 2*(2*x)
```

And so on: to recurse `n` times we just run `sumK (... (sumK id)...)` where `sumK` is applied `n` times. Equivalently, this can be written as the composition `sumK . sumK . ... . sumK $ id`. So, to obtain that it is enough to generate a list `[sumK,sumK,...]`, compose them, and apply `id` at the end.

```
sum10 :: Float -> Float
sum10 = compose (replicate 10 sumK) id

compose :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
compose = foldr (.) id
```

If you prefer, you can write a small general helper:

```
recurseOnly :: Int -> ((a->a)->(a->a)) -> (a->a)
recurseOnly n funK = compose (replicate n funK) id

sum10 :: Float -> Float
sum10 = recurseOnly 10 sumK
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sumTen :: Float -> Float
sumTen x = go 10 x
    where
      go n x
       | n == 0 = x
       | otherwise = x + go (n-1) (2*x)
```

There are two main points here: `go` is a simple recursive function of two arguments, which passes along the `n` to make you stop at the right time. But because you don't want to expose that argument, the top-level `sumTen` function is just a partially-applied version of `go`. You could even write this as:

```
sumTen = go 10
  where go n x = -- ...
```

Which one you prefer is a style choice, really.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this even:

```
sumTen x = sum $ take (10+1) $ iterate (* 2) x
```

Comment: This doesn't actually do the same thing as the recursive version, because the doubling and the adding are intermingled in the original function. This "simplification" isn't really faithful.

Comment: The compiler via loop fusion and deforestation can do the intermingling itself.

Comment: I don't mean you missed some optimizations, I mean your code is incorrect: it produces different results than the code OP was trying to produce. Compare with my straightforward recursive version, for example.